# SQL JOIN to Only One Row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 sale data tables that have no common keys, just sale date and customer name. I want to join them so that for each row from table A there will be at most 1 match from table B, or 0 if none is found. The problem is if the same customer shows up twice on the same date. So if I have data like these

```
Table A                             Table B

Customer | Date       | Receipt     Customer | Date       | Invoice
===============================     ===============================
John     | 2018-01-01 | A           John     | 2018-01-01 | C
John     | 2018-01-01 | B           John     | 2018-01-01 | D
```

How do I get this

```
Result

Customer | Date       | Receipt | Invoice
=========================================
John     | 2018-01-01 | A       | C
John     | 2018-01-01 | B       | D
```

It does not matter whether receipt A is matched with Invoice C or D, as long as each is paired once. Currently my query joins all of them, AC, AD, BC, BD

Edit: to clarify, I can't have duplicates from either table. One invoice and receipt can only appear once.
So either one of these results are acceptable:

- AC and BD
- AD and BC

Comment: You need some way of uniquely identifying rows in each of the given tables.

Comment: There might be a solution for your problem but it will be dirty and unreliable no matter how you do it (What if two people with the same name order something on the same day?). You need to have a proper structure first, and a proper structure (=schema) includes primary keys to be able to build foreign keys upon using index.

Comment: I understand that, but I am combining data from 2 separate systems (both of which aren't mine, I can't modify them), so I need a way to do this. Oh and the customer names are usually long company names anyway so there's less chance of a name duplicate.

Comment: "I need a way to do this" is a *far* cry from "I need a way to do this *in SQL*."  Please see my answer - this sort of thing really really really needs to be done in the display layer, not in the result SQL's returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain, because you need to enumerate the two tables and then either `join` or aggregate.  Here is one way:

```
select customer, date, max(receipt) as receipt, max(invoice) as invoice
from ((select a.customer, a.date, a.receipt,
              (@rnr := if(@cd = concat_ws(';', customer, date), @rnr + 1,
                          if(@cd := concat_ws(';', customer, date), 1, 1)
                         )
              ) as seqnum
       from a cross join
            (select @rnr := 0, @cd := '') params
       order by a.customer, a.date
      ) union all
      (select b.customer, b.date, b.invoice,
              (@rni := if(@cd = concat_ws(';', customer, date), @rni + 1,
                          if(@cd := concat_ws(';', customer, date), 1, 1)
                         )
              ) as seqnum
       from b cross join
            (select @rni := 0, @cd := '') params
       order by a.customer, a.date
      )
     ) cd
group by customer, date, seqnum;
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but I shuddered when I saw that code.  I can just envision the look on the dev's face that inherits this and has to perform maintenance/expansion on the stored proc that uses it...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a distinct after you've joined your two tables since you only want distinct records?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Customer,
a.Date, 
a.Receipt, 
b.Invoice 
FROM Table_A a

JOIN Table_B b
ON a.Customer = b.Customer
AND a.Date = b.Date
```

Comment: Because then there will be duplicates, AD and BD for example, sql sees them as distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give an answer you're probably not going to like: this shouldn't be done in SQL.  This is a presentation/display issue.

Do this sort of work in the layer that's displaying the data to the user, not the SQL back end.  Are they looking it up in a web page?  Then have the web page get the raw data and format it as needed - have it put the contents of each day's Receipts or each day's Invoices in separate divs.  Is SQL sending out an email with this data?  Then don't have it generate a plain-text email - have it generate HTML and put the data into table cells (so you don't have to coordinate rows between two sets of data with possibly differing amounts of data.)

You really don't want to be playing the game of trying to make SQL output look pretty from within SQL.  Because, honestly, the code in the answer you've accepted may *work* correctly, but I'd hate to be trying to maintain it over the years...

Comment: No, it's not a presentation/display issue, because this will insert data to my table. This is pulling data from 2 third party databases to insert into mine, so it's a data issue

Comment: ... no, it's not.  There's no reason you can't pull this data and store it in a proper, normalized manner in your database (if this doesn't make sense, you can do some googling on 'SQL Normalization' and get a lot of good info on what I'm talking about.)  And if nobody needs to *see* the data in this format, there's definitely no good reason to *store* it in this manner.

Comment: Oh yes there is, I can't do anything about their databases, I have no control over the third party systems. I can only process the output. My database is normalized, theirs aren't